# Connotation of boob job

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

I suppose everyone has at least heard of the slangy terms *handjob* & *blowjob*, both relating to sexual activities. However, the other day I was watching the TV show Friends and I heard the term *boob job* referring to getting breast implants. I wondered if the same would apply to a woman who'd like to get implants on her buttocks, perhaps *buttjob*, or something along those lines—— but all I could find was more sexual insinuations about that term as well. Don't get me wrong, I don't have my mind in the gutter here, but why is it that the term *boob job* seems to have no sexual insinuation if it's formed the same way as the other three? I understand that *handjob* & *blowjob* wouldn't convey the idea of getting implants in one's body, but at least *buttjob* or *assjob* could work the same way *boob job* does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many *job* phrases, especially in slang, and while there are *blowjobs* and *handjobs* and *rim jobs*, most *jobs* do not have sexual connotations. They simply follow one of the various conventional definitions of *[job](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/job)* as a task, a piece of work, an occupation, or a crime. Referring to such things as *jobs* is informal; in formal registers, I would only use *job* in its basic sense of an occupation or duty, or when part of an idiomatic set phrase like *[odd job](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/odd-job)* or *[joe job](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/joe_job)*.

There are *[mcjobs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mcjob)* and *[day jobs](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=day%20job)* for the under-employed and the under-discovered, *[lube jobs](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lube-job)* and *salvage jobs* for pre- and post-crashed cars, and *[hatchet jobs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hatchet%20job)* and *[snow jobs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snow%20job)* for your enemies. If you *[pull a job](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pull+a+job)* on a bank you've done a *[bank job](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/job#1-4)*, which might make you a *[nut job](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38976)* or a whack job, especially if it isn't an *[inside job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_job)* you thought up at your *[desk job](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/desk-job)*.

Its use to refer to cosmetic surgery is so common that the American Heritage Dictionary [includes it as a definition](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=job):

> An operation done to improve one's appearance, or the result of such an operation. Often used in combination: *a face job*.

While I don't think *face job* is common, the *[nose job](http://www.webmd.com/beauty/nose-job/rhinoplasty-nose-job-directory)* (for cosmetic rhinoplasty) certainly is. The Online Etymology Dictionary traces it to [1963](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=nose%20job), but Google Books finds it in a [1947 English textbook](http://books.google.com/books?ei=LDNcVPHJEoieyATCp4LYAw&id=xpsfAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22nose%20job%22)

[image: I want a 'nose job,' but my parents won't let me get one.]

In addition to *nose jobs*, there are *eye jobs* and, as you note, *boob jobs*, but not every type of cosmetic surgery is best known as a *job*: there are various *lifts*, *tucks*, and *implants*, for example, for more specific work. It is common to hear *breast implants* instead of a *boob job*, being somewhat more formal but not as clinical as *breast augmentation*, and being more descriptive of the procedure, as technically speaking, breast reduction and breast shaping could also be argued to be "boob jobs." And rather than a *butt job*, you're more likely to hear of *butt implants* as one method of [buttock augmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttock_augmentation).

Comment: Excellent answer, very informative. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nice job explaining how the modifier is more like a nose than a hand for the O.P.'s cited phrase. Also, it's interesting how _nose job_ was put in ‘quotes’ in the pre-1963 reference.